# Adding divider between horizontal sass susy grid

Tags: css, sass, susy

I'm trying to figure out how to add vertical dividers between my horizontal layout. I have 3 columns and I'd like dividers to the right and left of the middle column.

Typically I would add an `:after` rule in CSS to draw it after each element and a `:last-child` to exclude it from the end, but the problem is Susy's `span()` function fills up any room available to add a 1 pix divider between the elements.

Here is what my code looks like:

Sass:

```
nav {
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        li {
            width: span(1 of 3);
            float: left;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of grid system like Susy is to fill up all the available space by arranging elements. But there are a couple of options for adding borders:

1) Add `box-sizing: border-box;`, probably by putting `@include border-box-sizing;` in your `li` declaration. See more on [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

2) Use [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline), which doesn't add to an element's width. Example: `outline: solid black 1px;`